# Read all lines between two string

Tags: python, readlines

I want to extact lines from an xml that are between   from my xml. Here is an example:

```
<userData code="viPartListRailML" value="1">
            <partRailML s="0.0000000000000000e+00" id="0"/>
            <partRailML s="2.0000000000000000e+01" id="1"/>
            <partRailML s="9.4137883373059267e+01" id="2"/>
        </userData>
```

Here is my code, that I was trying:

```
import re

shakes = open("N:\SAJAT_MAPPAK\IGYULAVICS\/adhoc\pythonXMLread\probaxml\github_minta.xml", "r")
for x in shakes:
    if "userData" in x:
        print x
        continue
    if "/userData" in x:
        break
```

The problem is that it still gives back only the lines that contain `<userData` or `</userData>`
How to modify it to get the lines between these two "words"

Comment: You only have `if` statements for strings that contain `'userData'` and `'userData'` so you'll need to add either another `if` or `else` statement or have some default code.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python and for info about using Python's XML parsing library.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is one `<userData>` block in your file, your can extract lines within block by:

```py
shakes = open("./file.xml", "r")
inblock = False
for x in shakes:
    if "/userData" in x:
        inblock = False
    if inblock:
        print(x)
    if "userData" in x:
        inblock = True
```

But read your file with a xml parser is more robust, like:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('file.xml')

for data in tree.getroot().iter('userData'):
    for child in data:
        print(ET.tostring(child))
        # or something else, eg:
        # print(child.tag)
```

*BTW, use Python3 whenever possible, Python2 is retired.*

Comment: inblock is True after "/userData" because it matches with "userData" as well. I didn't think that first either...

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is to add a variable, which tells if you are between those words:

```
shakes = open("N:\SAJAT_MAPPAK\IGYULAVICS\/adhoc\pythonXMLread\probaxml\github_minta.xml", "r")
t=False
for x in shakes:
    if t:
        print(x) # also /userdata -line is printed
    if "/userData" in x:
        t=False
    elif "userData" in x: # this matches /userData as well--> elif
        t=True
```

Comment: you could move the `if t` to the end. Or change the order, like @Chang Ye's answer

Comment: Correct, however, I was thinking that /userData -line print is intended functionality (- and in case not, I added the comment into the code)

Comment: Changed if "userData" order and another if to elif

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) to reach the `<userData` part and then use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to read until `</userData`:

```
import itertools as it

result = it.takewhile(
    lambda x: '</userData' not in x,
    it.dropwhile(
        lambda x: '<userData' not in x,
        text.splitlines()
    )
)
print('\n'.join(result))
```

If you want to skip the `<userData` element you can add [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
result = it.takewhile(
    lambda x: '</userData' not in x,
    it.islice(it.dropwhile(
        lambda x: '<userData' not in x,
        text.splitlines()
    ), 1, None)
)
print('\n'.join(result))
```